# Eclipse Barrio plugin - how does it work?

Tags: eclipse

Based on the screenshot and description, the [Barrio](https://code.google.com/p/barrio/) plugin looks like it does exactly what I want a plugin to do.  I've installed it, apparently successfully; it's listed in my installed software.  But I don't see any new views, options, or controls in my Eclipse UI.

So, uh... how does it work?  I'm particularly interested in how to make it "extract the graph from project source code."  Has anyone ever actually used this plugin?  It looks pretty unknown, judging by the number of relevant Google hits.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah, hidden in plain sight!  It created a new top-level "Barrio" menu, peer to "File", "Edit", "Help", etc.  It has an option called "Open Barrio Perspective", which opens a perspective called "Cluster Analysis".